# Проблема с q-learning'ом

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Всех приветствую. Недавно начал знакомиться с Reinforcement learning-ом. У меня возникло такое недопонимание:

Для q-learning'a необходима так называемая "таблица вознаграждений". И вот сам вопрос:

Во время создание самой таблицы мне нужно указывать определенную награду за определенное действие в определенной ситуации. К примеру:

У меня есть, допустим, какая-нибудь машинка на arduino. На ней висят 2 датчика расстояния, слева и справа. Мне необходимо, чтобы машина ехала точно посередине от стен (30 см от 1 стены и 30 от другой, к примеру).

С q-learning мне нужно построить такую таблицу:

state : [0, 1, 2] - где 0 - близко к левой стене, 1 - близко к правой, 2 - ровно середина.

action  : [0, 1, 2] - где 0 - повернуть направо, 1 - налево, 2 - ехать прямо.

reward : [[10, -1, -1], [-1, 10, -1], [-1, -1, 10]].

И такой метод получения текущего состояния:

```
int GetCurrentState(){   

    if (DistanceToLeftWall == 30 && DistanceToRigtWall == 30){   

         return 2; 

    }

    if (DistanceToLeftWall < 30){
        return 0;        
    }

    if (DistanceToRightWall < 30){ 

          return 1; 

    }   
     }
```

Отсюда вопрос: Смысл q-learning'a, если я могу вместо возвращения текущего состояния сразу описывать логику?

К примеру так:

```
void main(){   

    if (DistanceToLeftWall == 30 && DistanceToRigtWall == 30){   

         RightForward();

    }

    if (DistanceToLeftWall < 30){
        TurnRight();  
    }

    if (DistanceToRightWall < 30){ 

          TurnLeft();

    }   

}
```

Я более чем уверен, что я чего-либо не дочитал или что-то не так понял. Хотелось бы об этом просить знающих людей.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Просто задача не подходящая для машинного обучения. В такой простой ситуации действительно лучше прямо кодом логику описать.